# Get column/row vector from python-numpy matrix formatted as column/row

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

When I select a column or row in python-numpy I always have to reformat it so that it becomes an actual column or row vector.
So I always have to write code like in the end of my example, which looks totally over-engineered to me.
Is there a way to select a column or row from a matrix in a way that I directly get the correct formatted vector?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.zeros((2,3))
>>> # Show the size of the matrix
>>> print(A.shape)
(2, 3)
>>> # This is not a row vector
>>> print(A[1,:].shape)
(3,)
>>> # Get a real row vector (looks totally over-engineered)
>>> print(np.array([A[1,:]]).shape)
(1, 3)
```

Comment: You can try: `A[1:2,:]`

Comment: @Shaido in fact, if I pass a list I get the correct answer. A proper solution is also `print(A[[1],:].shape)`

Comment: Why do you need a 2d result?

Comment: @hpaulj Some backends I use need such an input.

Comment: I am sorry for contacting you this way (my comment isnt related to your input here). I came across a question you voted on in "triage" where you made the wrong choice. Please: study the help for triage carefully, to avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. I hope you see this as a chance to improve your voting. I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21074187. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me. If you give me a quick reply, I will immediately this comment here.